# Get list of shortcodes from content

Tags: php, shortcode

I need a list of every shortcode inside the content. Is there any way to list them?

This is what I need:

```
$str = '[term value="Value" id="600"][term value="Term" id="609"]';
```

So every shortcode should be inside the `$str`.

I found a code snippet to check if there is a shortcode. But how can I display them all?

```
$content = 'This is some text, (perhaps pulled via $post->post_content). It has a [gallery] shortcode.';

if( has_shortcode( $content, 'gallery' ) ) {
    // The content has a [gallery] short code, so this check returned true.

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way:

You can look at [has_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_shortcode/) and find the parsing there:

```
preg_match_all( 
    '/' . get_shortcode_regex() . '/', 
    $content, 
    $matches, 
    PREG_SET_ORDER
);
```

using the [get_shortcode_regex()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_shortcode_regex/) function for the regex pattern.

For non empty matches, you can then loop through them and collect the full shortcode matches with:

```
$shortcodes = [];
foreach( $matches as $shortcode ) {
    $shortcodes[] = $shortcode[0];
}
```

Finally you format the output to your needs, e.g.:

```
echo join( '', $shortcodes );
```

PS: It can be handy to wrap this into your custom function.

Comment: ps: it might be good to make sure a bracket exists in the content, e.g. with a simple `strpos` check, before parsing (just as in `has_shortcode()` ).

Comment: It works well if `$content` is `get_the_content()` but not if it's a custom field like `get_sub_field("textfield")`?!

Comment: It should work for all content that contains shortcodes. @Cray

Comment: Hmm, the same code is not working if I'm using `get_sub_field("textfield")`. It's the only difference there!?

Comment: Check the output of `get_sub_field("textfield");` first and make sure it contains shortcodes. @Cray

Comment: ah, I guess the shortcode is already processed. If I echo `get_the_content`, it shows me the shorcode with `[ ]`. If I echo `get_sub_field("textfield")`, it shows only the result?!

Comment: It works when I use the field like this: `get_sub_field("textfield", false, false);`

Comment: This will only get shortcodes on the top level, and not nested shortcodes

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the Shortcodes without the attributes, you can use this function:

```
function get_used_shortcodes( $content) {
    global $shortcode_tags;
    if ( false === strpos( $content, '[' ) ) {
        return array();
    }
    if ( empty( $shortcode_tags ) || ! is_array( $shortcode_tags ) ) {
        return array();
    }
    // Find all registered tag names in $content.
    preg_match_all( '@\[([^<>&/\[\]\x00-\x20=]++)@', $content, $matches );
    $tagnames = array_intersect( array_keys( $shortcode_tags ), $matches[1] );
    return $tagnames;
}
```

You will get an array of all shortcodes, that are used within the content you give it.

Comment: Thanks! But I need the attributes

Answer (score 1):

Love @birgire's accepted answer, but a limitation of it is that any nested shortcodes are missed. You can overcome this by creating a simple walker:

```
function all_shortcodes($content) {
    $return = array();

    preg_match_all(
        '/' . get_shortcode_regex() . '/',
        $content,
        $shortcodes,
        PREG_SET_ORDER
    );

    if (!empty($shortcodes)) {
        foreach ($shortcodes as $shortcode) {
            $return[] = $shortcode;
            $return = array_merge($return, all_shortcodes($shortcode[5]));
        }
    }
    return $return;
}

$shortcodes_including_nested = all_shortcodes($post_content);
```